# Django Migration not detected when models.py inside an folder in app

Tags: python, django, migration

Folder structure that I kept for my project is:

```
project:
    commons
        settings.py
        manage.py
    app
        models
            models.py
            __init__.py  ()

__init__.py

    from models import xx

on running ./manage.py makemigrations
```

no changes are getting detected.

I have added the app in

```
installed_apps of settings.py as 'app'.
```

Can this be achieved in django ?

Advance thanks for your time.

Comment: Do you import the `Models` from the inner models.py in the  `__init__.py` of the models package?

Comment: It could probably be because you need to do ./manage.py makemigrations appname

Comment: @e4c5 I don't think so. `makemigrations` without parameters will make migrations for all installed apps.

Comment: @schwobaseggl yep, that's what it says on paper ....

Comment: Please try to import the models in `models.py` in `__init__.py` file inside `models` package.

Comment: That's why I said add the app label to makemigrations. When makemigrations doesn't automatically detect changes, telling it what app name you want to work with does the trick

Answer (score 9):

`python manage.py makemigrations app`

it will create the missing `migrations` folder

or you can manually create the `migrations` folder in your app with the `__init__.py` inside

it is skipping over your app because that folder does not exist